# MySQL export wihout /r /n

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a problem with exporting from MySQL database. When i export table named: clanky_t where i store text for my www sites, it is exported with /r /n instead of rows and line breaks. Example:

```
INSERT INTO "clanky_t" ("idecko", "nazev", "anotace", "text", "datum_zapisu", "stavpublikace", "datum_publikace", "datum_expirace", "sekce", "ulozil", "vlastnik", "zmenil_id", "zmenil", "clankyKonec", "anketa", "link", "thema", "priloha", "ipublikace", "iexpirace", "klicova_slova", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10", "var11", "var12", "var13", "var14", "var15", "var16", "var17", "var18", "var19", "var20", "poradi", "linkTyp", "titulek", "description", "hlavicka") VALUES
 (91, 'O nás', '<div>\r\n<table class="intContentRight" style="height: 212px; width: 316px;" border="0">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td class="thead"><span style="font-size: large;"><strong>O NÁS</strong></span></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td class="openFalse"><a href="http://192.168.11.100/PROJECT/metaldyne/?p=clanky/historie">HISTORIE</a></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td class="openFalse"><a href="http://192.168.11.100/PROJECT/metaldyne/?p=clanky/soucasnost">SOUČASNOST</a></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td class="openFalse"><a href="http://192.168.11.100/PROJECT/metaldyne/?p=clanky/reference_1">REFERENCE</a></td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>\r\n<table style="width: 584px; height: 209px;">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td align="center"><a href="http://192.168.11.100/PROJECT/metaldyne/galerie/10002017.jpg" rel="lytebox[img]" data-lyte-options="slide:false group:rsimages" data-title=""><img src="http://192.168.11.100/PROJECT/metaldyne/image.php?img=galerie/10002017.jpg&amp;size=300" alt="" border="0" /></a></td>\r\n
```

What i'm trying to do is, to take clanky_t from MySQL and insert it into prepared MS SQL database with rows and linebreaks instead of /r /n.

Is there a way to tell ms sql to make linebreaks and rows when inserting to the table or Export it as it is in the mysql database ?

Sorry if it does not make any sense, it is hard for me to explain, i'm still a novice.

> EDIT:

Solved by updating/replacing the inserted data in the mssql table:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(column_name as NVarchar(MAX)),'\r\n','') AS NText)
```

Comment: \r and \n are linebreaks. what's the mysql output you are looking for? this sounds like an export tweak more than a import tweak, siomething to be handled on mysql side. what about a string replace on the output produced by mysql?

Comment: Typically when inserting to SQL Server you'd insert `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` for carriage return and linefeed, so you'd need to translate your MySQL escape sequences to those somehow. (Though if I were to import a bunch of data from MySQL to SQL Server, I might consider using SSIS instead, which would probably just handle the data properly.)

Comment: Use SSIS service to import database form mysql to mssql or follow this one, may this will help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server

Comment: I would love to avoid recreating mssql database because the one i already have is working fine and the problem lies only in the format of data in the table. Everything is fine just those linebreaks are showing as /r/n . It is really anoying im alread stuck for 2 hours now and still not even close to the answer.

Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: How do you export data exactly? We can't help you fix a process we know nothing about.

Comment: I Already solved the problem :),I exported data from phpMyAdmin in .sql format, inserted into MSSQL table and then used REPLACE to get rid of /r/n in the columns.